# How to get user create date only in android

Tags: android, api, date, server, retrofit

I am using retrofit. I get data (date & time) from server. But Create Date is `(2016-01-22 15:22:37)`. I want to show only date `(2016-01-22)`.

```
user = StoreUtil.getInstance().selectFrom("users");
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getNotSending(user.getId(), new Callback<List<MyPending>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<MyPending> myPendings, Response response) {
        txt_taker_name.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingInformation().getName());
        txt_taker_address.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_address)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingInformation().getAddress());
        txt_cargo_name.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_cargo_name)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingTransactionDetail().get(0).getCargo().getName());
        txt_cargo_qty.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_cargo_qty)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingTransactionDetail().get(0).getCargo().getQuantity());
        txt_total_weight.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_confirm_totalweight)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getTotalWeight());
        txt_total_deliver_charges.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_confirm_totalcharges)
            + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getTotalCost());
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(
            myPendings.get(0).getShippingTransactionDetail().get(0).getCargo().getCreatedAt());
        txt_deliver_date.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_deliver_date) + ":" + " " + date);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismissWithFailure();
    }
});
```

Comment: Its simple. Just split the date as per your requirement and use that splitted date.

Answer (score 2):

simple way is just split date

```
String dates = myPendings.get(0).getShippingTransactionDetail().get(0).getCargo().getCreatedAt();
if(!dates.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
String date[] = dates.split(" ");
Log.e("FINAL DATE-->","-->"+date[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am putting my code that i use to format the date to a particular format. Try it.

```
    String mytime="Jan 17, 2012";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MMM dd, yyyy");
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

    System.out.println(finalDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert date

```
    public String changedate(String pastdate)  {
    final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String newDateString = "";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(pastdate);
        sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
        newDateString = sdf.format(d);
    }catch (ParseException e)
    {
    }
    return newDateString;
    }
```